# Converting Nhibernate Object to JSON

Tags: c#, json, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, json.net

I am getting this error while I am converting.

> Initializing[Entity.Tag#8]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of
>   role: Entity.Tag.Feed, no session or session was closed

```
Feed feed = new Feed();

Tag tag = Tag.READ.ById(8);
feed.Tag.Add(tag);
feed.Language = ENLanguage.EN;
feed.Name = "Foo";

feed.Save();

string x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(feed);
```

**Feed Class**

```
public class Feed : BaseClass<Feed>
{
    public virtual int FeedId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
    public virtual ENLanguage Language { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public Feed()
    {
        Tag = new List<Tag>();
    }

    public virtual void AddTag(Tag tag)
    {
        tag.Feed.Add(this);
        Tag.Add(tag);
    }
}
```

**Feed Map**

```
public class FeedMap : ClassMap<Feed>
{
    public FeedMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.FeedId);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Tag).Cascade.All().Table("FeedTag");
        Map(x => x.Language).CustomType<short>();
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

**Tag Class**

```
public class Tag : BaseClass<Tag>
{
    public virtual int TagId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Feed> Feed { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Tag Map**

```
public class TagMap : ClassMap<Tag>
{
    public TagMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.TagId);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Feed).Cascade.All().Inverse().Table("FeedTag");
    }
}
```

**Save Method**

```
    using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(x);

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's you session starting and ending?  I've had that problem before when I've loaded something in the controller, but when the view trys to do something with it, the session is closed.

Comment: I think you are asking for save method? I added to question.

Comment: oh!   you are closing the session straight away..... that means it can't lazy load things later

Comment: I am not familiar with nhibernate, what should be the right way to do?

Comment: are you doing a web app? or something else?

Comment: Yeah Its a web application

Comment: quite often people will open a session for the entire request, and close it once the request has finished

Comment: this makes me question my framework structure :( I didn't know I will need session once I done with db methods.

Comment: @Mert you are not really done with the database. You loaded only the root of an object graph and depending on the use case load additional information later, hence you still need database access. NHibernate supports you with only loading what you need through lazy loading but if you know what you need prefetching it will increase performance a lot. You can't do that with your current framework. So if you like to work with ActiveRecord pattern (domain classes have data access methods), i urge you to look into Castle.ActiveRecord which already implemented it on top of NHibernate

Comment: Property `Tag` should be `Tags` because it is a collection of tags no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your session is ended too quickly.  You only open it for your save.

try

```
using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
  Feed feed = new Feed();

  Tag tag = Tag.READ.ById(8);
  feed.Tag.Add(tag);
  feed.Language = ENLanguage.EN;
  feed.Name = "Foo";

  feed.Save();

  string x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(feed);
}
```

Comment: What if I only cover SerializeObject with using? does that work? If It is I am planing to create ToJson generic method which handles sessin inside it. so I could use it  like "feed.ToJson()"

Comment: [JsonIgnore] is solved my problem but I learned something new from you guys! appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem that you don't initialize lazy collection
IList Feed of class Tag when you get object from database

```
Tag.READ.ById(8); // in that method you have to initialize Feed
```

something like

```
using(session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
var TagObjectFromDb = session.Get<Tag>(id);
NHibernateUtil.Initialize(TagObjectFromDb.Feed);//initialize lazy collection, 
return TagObjectFromDb;
}
```

and

```
Feed fbfeed = new Feed();//fbfeed - typo?

Tag tag = Tag.READ.ById(8);
feed.Tag.Add(tag);//fbfeed - typo?
```

Comment: READ.ById is a generic method. What you are suggesting is not suitable. any way around?

Comment: when you call string x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(feed);
instance feed must by fully initialized. For collection properties like IList<Feed> Feed or IList<Tag> Tag you have to call NHibernateUtil.Initialize() inside opened session

Comment: In your case i can think of simple solution,since you don't have opened session, which you could use to initialize collection.
 Or maybe you have but i can't see that in your example.

Comment: [JsonIgnore] is solved my problem but I learned something new from you guys! appreciated!